# Fast query with optional parameters without dynamic query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

After [searching for a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649036/how-to-handle-optional-parameters-in-sql-query) on the web for a slow query. I notice that converting the query to a dynamic query would make it execute faster. It seems to do with the wrong execution plan being used when different parameters are passed.

This is slow

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM TransactionHistory
WHERE (ProductID = pProductId OR pProductId IS NULL)
AND (ReferenceOrderID = pOrderId OR pOrderId IS NULL)
AND (TransactionType = pTransactionType OR pTransactionType IS NULL)
```

This is fast (please ignore the bad query and injection)

```
vSql := 'SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM TransactionHistory WHERE 1=1 '

IF pProductId IS NOT NULL THEN
    vSql := vSql || ' AND ProductID = ' || pProductId
END IF;

IF pOrderId IS NOT NULL THEN
    vSql := vSql || ' AND ReferenceOrderID = ' || pOrderId
END IF;

IF pTransactionType IS NOT NULL THEN
    vSql := vSql || ' AND TransactionType = ' || pTransactionType
END IF;

OPEN pCursor FOR vSql;
```

I'm currently working on 10g but will be moving to 11g soon. With 11g, is there a way to have the query run fast without the dynamic query?

Comment: Are you talking about bind variable peeking creating a suboptimal plan if the first values used are not representative? ([As in this story](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/another-debugging-story.html)). And you want a hard parse with a unique query instead, which will affect the SQL statement cache? If so then 11g's adaptive cursor sharing may help, perhaps?

Comment: @AlexPoole still doing some research about this. You might be giving me a good path here.

Comment: @the_lotus The answers in the linked question were partially wrong.  It is possible to use a static SQL statement for this kind of logic and have it perform well.  See my new answer in that question.  TLDR; use `NVL` and the optimizer will add a `FILTER` operation and choose a different execution plan at run time.