# How to build where clause with optional search parameters

Tags: oracle, optional-parameters

There are four field in the page lets say

```
EMPLOYEE ID
DEPT
LOCATION
UNIT:
```

User might enter any of the field values all are optional, if he enter `EMPLOYEE ID` then the query should return rows related to that `EMPLOYEE ID`. If he enters only `LOCATION` then the query should return all the employees of that location. How to write the where clause condition with optional parameters.

Comment: and (:val = employeeid or :val is null) use this block. if value defined it is used in query if not then null is null )

Comment: I tired with your option, it doesn't return what i am expecting. Can you show me for all the four fields how to frame the where clause.

Answer (score 7):

Oracle will likely build a well-optimized query if you use `NVL` in your predicates:

```
select *
  from employee
 where employee_id = nvl(:employee_id, employee_id)
   and dept = nvl(:dept, dept)
   and location = nvl(:location, location)
   and unit = nvl(:unit, unit)
```

The above code is mostly equivalent to LeoLozes's answer.  Although his answer is more readable, in this case the cryptic version may run much faster.  One important difference is that the above code will not work if the column is NULL.  If you have nullable columns you'll need to use something like LeoLoze's answer, since `null = null` is not true.

Oracle is used to the `NVL` trick, and can automatically convert this static query into a dynamic query using a FILTER operation.  The execution plan will have both a FULL TABLE SCAN and and INDEX RANGE SCAN, and will pick the appropriate one at run-time, depending on the value of the bind variable.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28307941/409172) for some sample code demonstrating how this works.

Comment: Totally true, I forgot that this was the best way to do it :)

Comment: This will do not select entries whith at least one column value set to NULL.
If UNIT is null for one entry, and the parameter :unit is null too, then the condition `unit = nvl(:unit, unit)` will be `unit = nvl(null, null)` which is equivalent to `unit = null` which is always false (we need to use `UNIT IS NULL` instead).

Comment: @AntoineMartin Thank you for your comment.  I added a warning about nullable columns to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's always the (very poorly optimized) option of doing it this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE (EMPLOYEE_ID = :p_EMPLOYEE_ID OR :p_EMPLOYEE_ID IS Null)
  AND (DEPT = :p_DEPT OR :p_DEPT IS Null)
  AND (LOCATION = :p_LOCATION OR :p_LOCATION IS Null)
  AND (UNIT = :p_UNIT OR :p_UNIT IS Null)
```

I only use it in tables with a small amount of rows. 
It's however recommended to have at least one mandatory parameter that will use indexed fields (since here, you'll have a *TABLE ACCESS FULL*).

Comment: Not sure if Oracle evaluates from left to right but I always write:
(:p_EMPLOYEE_ID IS Null or EMPLOYEE_ID = :p_EMPLOYEE_ID)

Comment: @Rene The order of conditions does not matter at all. The problem for Oracle is that the SQL's exec plan has to be optimized for ANY combination of bind parameter values. It has to be optimized before Oracle even sees bind variables.  For 4 possible columns on search criteria it is still possible to have 2^4-1 possible SQL texts to use.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against this thinking for real world applications .Submitting   dynamic style query to database has proven issues in terms of security ,optimization and functional correctness .
Since there will be some application code between user interface and the database, its better build the query as per need there and then submit it for execution .

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
  from employee
 where nvl(employee_id, -1) = coalesce(:employee_id, employee_id, -1)
   and nvl(dept, -1) = coalesce(:dept, dept, -1)
   and nvl(location, -1) = coalesce(:location, location, -1)
   and nvl(unit, -1) = coalesce(:unit, unit, -1)
```

The reasoning behind this is that using `nvl` the way Jon suggested has one drawback: if the field being tested is `null` itself, it will return `false` in that test because (I believe) for testing `null` you need to test it with `is null`.

`nvl` could be doing a `null = null` there instead of a `null is null`, returning wrong data and you won't even notice because it doesn't warn you.

Using `coalesce`, you will get `-1 = -1` (or whatever other value you would consider as impossible for the column) when both the parameter and the field are `null`

Answer (score 0):

Only safe way to write the code for this many is individual views based on what they are selecting, For example if  your using a Java GUI you are able to select the information depending on what they want to search by.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Are you suggesting the OP should create one view for each possible combination of search parameters? That would scale quite poorly (2**4 = 16 views for just 4 search parameters).