# If else in select query oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a variable v_brand in a sql procedure. If that variable is not null then

```
select * from table where column1 = someValue and brandColumn = v_brand;
```

If the variable is null

```
select * from table where column1 = someValue;
```

Best I could come up with is

```
IF v_brand IS NOT NULL THEN

 select * from table where column1 = someValue and brandColumn = v_brand;

ELSE

select * from table where column1 = someValue;

END IF:
```

The queries I will be using are hundreds of lines. Is there a way to combine both queries, as it seems more maintainable.

Comment: You could try `brandColunn = coalesce(v_brand, brandColumn)`

Comment: Looks like this will work. Please add this as answer, will accept as solution after trying it out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL - How to build where clause with optional search parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454886/oracle-sql-how-to-build-where-clause-with-optional-search-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can combine the 2 queries using some conditional logic

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column1 = someValue
AND (brandColumn = v_brand OR v_brand IS NULL);
```

check whether `v_brand` either =brandColumn or NULL

- `v_brand` is NULL + OR returns true (query returns all rows where column1 equals someValue -- regardless of brandColumn)
- `v_brand` not NULL -- (brandColumn = v_brand) will be evaluated(true--the row will be returned -- if false -- AND will be false + row will be excluded from result set)