# How to append a query in where clause of existing query

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

In Oracle form I have a query just like

```sql
if po_no is not null then
    str := str ||'and po_no = '||:block.po_no;
end if;
```

now I want to append the str in below query.

```sql
select po_no
   from po,
        po_det
   where po_id = p_det_id
      &str
```

I want to append the str in end of query but it gives
ORA-01722 error ..how i can do in right way..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL - How to build where clause with optional search parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454886/oracle-sql-how-to-build-where-clause-with-optional-search-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate `str` to the rest of the query.

Pay attention to leading space (in front of the `AND`):

```
if po_no is not null then
   str := str ||' and po_no = ' || :block.po_no;
end if;

select po_no
from po, po_det
where po_id = p_det_id || str;
```

---

You didn't explain where exactly you'll be using that *dynamic WHERE clause*; if it is to filter rows fetched in a data block, consider using `SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY` built-in and its `ONETIME_WHERE` (or `DEFAULT_WHERE`) property (read more about it in Oracle Online Help system).

---

**[EDIT]**

I'm still not sure what is what in this query, but - to me - it looks as if you don't need `IF` at all, but use query which looks like this:

```
select po_no
  into v_po_no
  from po, po_det
  where po_id = p_det_id
    and (po_no = :block.po_no or po_no is null);     --> this substitutes your IF
```

Once again: to me, it is unclear what is exactly `po_no` (column? block field? variable?), but that's more or less what you might need to do.

---

**[EDIT #2]**

Dynamic SQL:

```
declare
  str    varchar2(500);
  result number;
begin
  str := 'select po_no from po, po_det where po_id = p_det_id ' ||
         case when po_no is not null then ' and po_no = :a'
         end;
         
  execute immediate str into result using :block.po_no;
end;
```

Comment: i am using it in when-button-press trigger and want to append the criteria which is build in Str variable and at then end append this Str variable to query just like this mention in below:

     ``select po_no into v_po_no
          from po, po_det
            where po_id = p_det_id || str; ``

my question how to concat the str in existing query at the end of where clause.

Comment: OK; and what is PO_NO you use in IF? This: IF PO_NO IS NOT NULL >> what is that PO_NO? Could you also edit original question you posted and post the whole trigger code? It would be simpler for us to assist if we knew what is what.

Comment: Sir po_no comes from text item and any string value come from lov..like po_no='po-123'..actual problem I am facing is to cancat str with where claus at the end and str just like we do this in Oracle report like &str

Comment: select po_no
  into v_po_no
  from po, po_det
  where po_id = p_det_id
    and (po_no = :block.po_no or 
                   po_no is null)   why we can not dynamic it? Means why not we put in variable like str =' and po_no='||:block.text_field;     and the put str in where clause at the end

Comment: Because that's not how dynamic SQL works in Oracle. You could compose a SELECT statement and execute it using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Though, pay attention to what this query returns - must be a single value because - if it doesn't return anything, Oracle will raise NO_DATA_FOUND; if it returns more than a single value, it'll return TOO_MANY_ROWS.

Comment: Put this part of yours reply in a variable and the append the variable to existing query forgot the if condition.
   Str:= and (po_no = :block.po_no or 
         po_no is null)

Comment: Sorry will be count(po_no) no too many rows return only single value returned it's gurunteed

Comment: Can you please write how the above scanario can be build in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement

Comment: But it's work in Oracle report we build many criteria in string form then send string to report and put at last of query with &str

Comment: Edited, with dynamic SQL. As of the fact that it works in Oracle Reports: yes, it does, but that's a **different tool** with different rules.

Comment: Agreed can you forward what and how the execute immediate built for such scanario

Comment: Dynamic SQL is usually used when you have to include different table or column names in the same query. In this (your) case, I'd use code I posted in my 1st EDIT.

Comment: Ok thanks gotted...I appreciate yours support

Comment: If I used set_block_property and default_where..and execute the block it give more row while I required to count the result in this scanario how I can count(po_no)

Comment: You certainly wouldn't use SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY for that purpose, it just doesn't make any sense.