# If the null or empty list does not filter

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jpa

Does anyone know how I can do it if the List is null or empty and does not search the list (Bring all elements)?

```
@Query("SELECT new ReasonCodeCounter(credittype, reasontext, reasoncode, decisionresult, SUM(total))\r\n"

+ "FROM ReasonCodeCounter\r\n"

+ "WHERE createdate >= :startDate AND createdate <= :endDate\r\n"

+ "AND (credittype IN (:credittypeVAR))\r\n"

+ "AND (decisionresult IN (:decisionresultVAR))\r\n"

+ "AND (valoracaoproposta IN (:valoracaopropostaVAR))\r\n"

+ "AND (produto IN (:produtoVAR))\r\n"

+ "AND (regiaobalcao IN (:regiaobalcaoVAR))\r\n"

+ "AND (ctransorigid IN (:ctransorigidVAR))\r\n"

+ "GROUP BY credittype, reasontext, reasoncode, decisionresult")

List<ReasonCodeCounterParent> getOccurrencesOfReasonCodesFilters(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate,

List<String> credittypeVAR, List<String> decisionresultVAR, List<String> valoracaopropostaVAR, List<String> produtoVAR,

List<String> regiaobalcaoVAR, List<String> ctransorigidVAR);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build where clause with optional search parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454886/how-to-build-where-clause-with-optional-search-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we do it as

```
AND (credittype IN (:credittypeVAR) or :credittypeVAR is null)
```

You'd apply it to all parameters.

Comment: 0


when I use you code I have this error ""message": "Unknown wrap conversion requested: java.util.ArrayList to java.lang.String : org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringJavaType (java.lang.String)",

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Java. Code I posted is what we use in SQL, and it *really* does what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this way doesn't work in Oracle, it should... But I solved it another way.

I'm using Oracle and that might be why it doesn't do it the simple way... I created logic for the lists and I'm using it this way

“AND ((credittype IN (:credittypeVAR)) OR (‘all’) IN (:credittypeVAR)) \r\n”

If the list is null or empty, I put the value ‘all’ (I created a method for this).