# Oracle SQL NVL return more than one value

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to list active and inactive employee when pIsActive is null.

pIsActive = (0,1,null)

```
select e.*
from employee e
where e.id in (1,2,3,4,5)
and (e.isactiv = NVL(pIsActive, (0,1)));
```

Comment: Hi. Are you probably looking for `isactiv = NVL(pIsActive,isactiv)` If I don't misunderstand ( presuming the column `isactiv` has values 1 and 0 only  )  ..?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build where clause with optional search parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454886/how-to-build-where-clause-with-optional-search-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NVL` and `COALESCE` will only return a scalar value not a list of values.

Instead, use `OR` and `IN`:

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM   employee e
WHERE  e.id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
AND    (  e.isactiv = pIsActive
       OR (pIsActive IS NULL AND e.isactiv IN (0,1))
       );
```

You could also write the query as:

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM   employee e
WHERE  e.id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
AND    e.isactiv IN ( NVL(pIsActive, 0), NVL(pIsActive, 1) );
```

But I find the first option to be easier to understand and this second option I have to think about for a while to work out that you are effectively doing `e.isactive = pIsActive` if `pIsActive IS NOT NULL` and `e.isactive IN (0,1)` otherwise.