# Ignoring parameters if not required in Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, join, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where there are `4-5 parameters` to filter query based on those parameters. I have created the procedure and data is also getting filtered, but I want to implement one thing that if sometimes user doesn't want to pass one of those parameters then the data is not getting filtered. Below is my query.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FETCH_CONS_REPORT_NEW(
        P_STATENAME IN VARCHAR2,
        P_CITYNAME  IN VARCHAR2,
        P_FROMDATE  IN DATE,
        P_TODATE    IN DATE,
        TBLOUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
    AS
      v_query_string    VARCHAR2 (9000);
      v_where_condition VARCHAR2 (9000);
    BEGIN
      OPEN TBLOUT FOR SELECT a.changerequestid, a.changerequestnumber, a.networktype, a.statename, a.cityname, a.description, a.createdon, a.lastmodifiedon, a.lastmodifiedby,a.band, b.sap_id, b.site_type, b.cr_category, b.latitude, b.longitude, b.approve_reject, b.CREATION_SAPID, b.APPROVED_BY, b.BACKHAUL, b.CR_JUSTIFICATIONS, b.CREATED_DATE FROM changerequests a inner join tbl_pre_post_hoto b ON a.changerequestid = b.CHANGEREQUEST_ID WHERE a.statename = 'Mumbai'
      -- and  a.cityname = null
      AND a.createdon >= TO_DATE(P_FROMDATE,'DD-MM-YY') AND a.lastmodifiedon <= TO_DATE(P_TODATE,'DD-MM-YY');
    END;
```

So how to handle that condition, please suggest ?

Comment: Does [How to build where clause with optional search parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454886/how-to-build-where-clause-with-optional-search-parameters) help?

Comment: Which parameter?   You don't appear to be using P_STATENAME  or P_CITYNAME  .   Also please format your SQL with some line breaks, so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `where` clause to something like this:

```
   WHERE     (   a.statename = p_statename
              OR p_statename IS NULL)
         AND (   a.cityname = p_cityname
              OR p_cityname IS NULL)
         AND a.createdon >= NVL (p_fromdate, TRUNC (SYSDATE))
         AND a.lastmodifiedon <= NVL (p_todate, TRUNC (SYSDATE))
```

As of `p_fromdate` and `p_todate`: parameters are already `date`s, you shouldn't `to_date` them. `nvl` function's value is set to `trunc(sysdate)` because I don't know what value you'd want to have if users don't pass them - fix it, if necessary.

Comment: what should be added in place of `SYSDATE` is it date format ?

Comment: SYSDATE if a function that returns DATE datatype, so - nothing should be added there (presuming that CREATEDON and LASTMODIFIED on columns are also DATEs, and yes - they should be. Not strings (i.e. VARCHAR2)).

Comment: will tet the logic and accept the answer in sometime