# Optional parameter in where condition - How to increase performance - PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pljson

I have a stored procedure that takes optional parameters from a Json structure. If the json values is provided, the parameters will be used as a conditions for the cursors. If json value is not provided I don't want that condition.
I have solved this by using Coalesce/Nvl in the sql condition. The problem is that the procedure is running for a very long time using Nvl/Coalesce. Is there a different method I can use which is more efficent? Perhaps dynamic sql?

My procedure:

```
Create or Replace Procedure findaccounts


(jsonIn IN clob,
 jsonOut OUT varchar2)
 As

obj json := json(jsonIn);
json_obj_out json;
json_lst json_list := json_list();

--Getstring is a function that sets variable to null if json value is not found
istatus varchar2(10) := GetString(obj json, 'status');
icreatedate := GetString(obj json, 'daysold'); 
iage int := GetString(obj json, 'age');
irownum int := GetString(obj json, 'rownum');

Begin
For rec in (Select A.accountnumber 
From Accounts A 
Inner Join Accountowner Ao On A.ownerId = Ao.Id
Where A.Status = iStatus
And A.daysold >= Coalesce(idaysold,A.daysold)
And Ao.Age = Coalesce(iAge,Ao.Age)
And rownum <= Coalesce(iRownum,5))

    loop

      obj := json();

      obj.put('accountnumber',Rec.accountnumber);
      json_lst.append(obj.to_json_value);

    end loop;

    json_lst.print;
    jsonOut := json_lst.to_char();  

End;
```

## resolved:

Performance boosted with dynamic sql. The option to have dynamic bind variables was resolved via dbms_sql package as execute immediate does not have this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally, `Coalesce` is a great way to handle optional search criteria.
Performancewise it is not good. The optimiser will not be able to optimize efficiently since it decides on the execution plan only once, optimising for the search criteria provided the first time the SQL is run.

If different executions plans would be required to get acceptable performance then you need to use different SQL statements for those different search patterns.

Here are two different solutions that I have used in the past:

1. Create several different SQL:s where each handles a subset of the possible search criteria that will share the same execution plan. In your case you could have one you use when `iAge` is `null`, another when `idaysold` is `null` and a third when neither is `null`.
2. Use dynamic SQL.

Comment: thanks. Issue resolved via dbms_sql. I could not find a way to have optional bind variables via execute immediate.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the `COALESCE()` function like this:

```
And ( idaysold IS NULL OR A.daysold >= idaysold )
And ( iAge     IS NULL OR Ao.Age    = iAge )
And ( ( iRownum  IS NULL AND ROWNUM <= 5 ) OR rownum <= iRownum )
```

Comment: Using functions in the `WHERE` clause can mean that a function-based index (or no index) is used instead of the column index. With this version there are no functions and the column indexes should be used (if present) - the OP can run an `EXPLAIN PLAN` on the two queries and see if there is a difference in the indexes used.

Comment: I would think the Oracle optimizer would look through `coalesce`/`nvl` and expand it before handing it over to the optimizer.

Comment: this will take a huge performance hit. Dynamic SQL or table functions seems to be the only way for multiple parameters

Answer (score 0):

`NVL` is usually the most efficient method for filtering by optional parameters.  It will generally perform better than `COALESCE`, `OR`, `CASE`, `DECODE`, and other similar solutions.

Switch back to that method, and if it's not working well there might be some other underlying problem.  Find the explain plan or the SQL monitoring report for the statement and post it here for further advice.

`NVL` usually works best because it is most likely to create `CONCATENATION` and `FILTER` operations.  (Note that a `FILTER` operation is *different* than the `Filter` section at the bottom of the explain plan.)  Those operations allow Oracle to create two different execution plans and choose one at run time depending on the bind variables.

Ideally the explain plan will look something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name       |
----------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |            |
|   1 |  CONCATENATION                |            |
|   2 |   FILTER                      |            |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL          | MYTABLE    |
|   4 |   FILTER                      |            |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MYTABLE    |
|   6 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | MYTABLE_PK |
----------------------------------------------------
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28307941/409172) for a test script that demonstrates how `NVL` can work.

I think there's a chance your code has two unlucky problems.  Without the `NVL` it won't generate separate execution plans.  With the `NVL` it may generate two plans, but perhaps both of them are bad.  Ff even the `NVL` won't generate separate plans then I suggest you look into Klas Lindbäck's answer.