# Adding conditions to the WHERE clause in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio, reporting-services, parameters

I am trying to create a report that allows the users filter out the products that they want to see by adding a parameter for the **Product_No** in my Oracle PL/SQL. I am using SQL Server Reporting Services that is connected with the Oracle database to my report.

My challenge is that if a user does not enter any **Product_No**, then my report should return all the products.

While the **Product_No** has already in my SELECT clause, I felt like adding some condition in the WHERE clause should work.

But something went wrong with my code, and it returns NULL if I do not enter the **Product_No** (if I enter a Product_No, then it works):

```
select Product_No, Product_Name
from Product_Table
where (:Product_No is null) OR
     ((:Product_No is not null) AND Product_No IN (:Product_No))
```

I simplified my code to make sure I am making sense. Could anyone give me some advice? Appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may create a function-based index

`create index idx_prod_no on Product_Table (nvl2(Product_No,1,0));`

and run statistics package the index to take effect :

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(myschema,'Product_Table',cascade=>true);
```

and use with this where condition to improve performance :

```
where nvl2(Product_No,1,0) = nvl2(:Product_No,1,0)
```

you may test it with including `execution plan` to show `index usage` :

```
SQL>set autotrace on;
SQL>var Product_No number; -- to see the results for NULL values
SQL>select Product_No, Product_Name
     from Product_Table
    where nvl2(Product_No,1,0) = nvl2(:Product_No,1,0);/

SQL>var Product_No number=1; -- to see the results for Product_No = 1 (as an example)
SQL>select Product_No, Product_Name
     from Product_Table
    where nvl2(Product_No,1,0) = nvl2(:Product_No,1,0);/
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading this post ([How to handle optional parameters in SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649036/how-to-handle-optional-parameters-in-sql-query/28307941#28307941)), I tested the following code, and it works:

```
WHERE Product_No = nvl(:Product_No, Product_No)
```

Basically, **nvl()** will return the Product_No if the user defined value is NULL.

However, the performance was not highly optimized I guess, because it checks every row in my table. I'm open to any better ideas...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Oracle but, based on how I would do this with SQL Server I would guess at...

```
select Product_No, Product_Name
from Product_Table
where (:Product_No is null) OR Product_No IN (:Product_No)
```